# Let $\, g \,$ be a function defined on $(a,b)$ such that $\, a<g(x)<x$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says :

[image]

What I guess option (A) is not possible. But,
I am not sure about the other options. Can someone explain? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is a constant, then $g(x) = c$ for all $x\in (a,b)$. By hypothesis,
$$
a < c < x \quad\forall x \in (a,b)
$$
This is impossible. Hence $g$ is non-constant; so (B) is true.

(A) Not possible because $g(x) < b$ for all $x\in (a,b)$

(C) Not necessarily, unless $a\geq 0$

(D) No. The graph of $g$ can bounce up and down between $y=a$ and $y=x$.

(E) No. Same reason as (D)

Comment: I am having trouble to understand the line "This is impossible. Hence $g$ is non-constant; so $(B)$ is true." Can you please add few details?

Comment: If $a < c < x$ for all $x$, then $a< c < a+1/n$, for all $n$ and $a+1/n \to a$

Comment: thanks a lot.That makes sense...